# Can't find termstore sharepoint for metadata

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata, term-store

I'm using PowerShell to add metadata to my termstore. When I go to the central administration, in metadata service application I can see that I have one termstore. But when I try to access it through :

```
$session = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
$termstore = $session.TermStores[$TermStoreData.termstore.name]
```

I don't find anything, and if I take a look at the `$session` object I see everything empty except the **"OfflineTermstoreNames"**,

Do you have any ideas how I could access to the metadata termstore ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Term store exists. I'm administrator, on the service, group, and set and yet powershell says there are no term stores. DefaultKeywordsTermStore DefaultSiteCollectionTermStor OfflineTermStoreNames TermStores e
------------------------ ----------------------------- --------------------- ---------- {Managed Metadata Service} {}

Comment: I have the same Problem. So when you say TurnOff the server do you really mean by server or MMS Service? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what I was looking for :

Being Administrator on the group, on the termset, on the termstore and on the service.

Turn off the server and turn it on.

It was ok for me

Answer (score 0):

Using:

$session = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $site

$termStore = $session.TermStores[$TermStoreData.termstore.name]

Does it works?

Comment: No, still the same proble, I have one item in OfflineTermstoreNames, and nothing in termstore :s

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking what termstores are available in $session.TermStores (by iterating on it)?

Are you having multiple Managed Metadata Services?

Comment: Yes, i've tried that, but there is no termstore "online" at all. 

When I look directly in my $session variable. I can only see one OfflineTermstoreName, all the other element are empty :s

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of your MetaData Service Instances are disabled. See:http://blogbaris.blogspot.ch/2013/04/offline-metadata-instances-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above with no success, but managed to bring my MM term store back online with a stop and start of ALL running instances of the Managed Metadata Web Service from the Services on Server page

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem.  Creating a new web app, importing terms to term store and session is null.
Solution was to open a new powershell session and ran my termstore related commands.